# open html file on sdcard with phonegap and jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, sd-card

i have some HTML files that users can download in runtime to sdcard. Now i want to create a link in my app to open those files. The problem is, i do not know what i should write in href property of the link tags to open the HTML files on sdcard

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In the congif.xml file from my Blackberry app project locate on:

```
C:\Dev\phonegap\BlackBerry-WebWorks\<project_folder>\www
```

there are this lines:

```
  <!-- PhoneGap API -->
  <access subdomains="true" uri="file:///store/home" />
  <access subdomains="true" uri="file:///SDCard" />
```

That config is granting access to those URI/resources, i think you can play around with that.

I have no idea how will be this URI on other plataforms, but is a good point to start the testing,

Good Luck!